# OpenCV C++, getting Region Of Interest (ROI) using cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, roi

I'm very new to OpenCV (started using it two days ago), I'm trying to cut a hand image from a depth image got from Kinect, I need the hand image for gesture recognition. I have the image as a `cv::Mat` type. My questions are:

1. Is there a way to convert `cv::Mat` to `cvMat` so that I can use `cvGetSubRect` method to get the Region of interest?
2. Are there any methods in `cv::Mat` that I can use for getting the part of the image?

I wanted to use `IplImage` but I read somewhere that `cv::Mat` is the preferred way now.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use the overloaded *function call* operator on the `cv::Mat`:

```
cv::Mat img = ...;
cv::Mat subImg = img(cv::Range(0, 100), cv::Range(0, 100));
```

Check the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat) for more information and for the overloaded function that takes a `cv::Rect`. Note that using this form of slicing creates a new matrix header, but does not copy the data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried the Range but it gave me a runtime error but the cv::Rect() worked just fine!

Comment: Could you edit your question with the `cv::Range` code that failed? Also, please accept my answer if it was helpful.

Comment: cv:Range gave me runtime error, but cv::Rect worked like a charm! thanks!

Comment: Yes it seems to be using Rect. Check http://jayrambhia.wordpress.com/2012/09/20/roi-bounding-box-selection-of-mat-images-in-opencv/ for an example.

Answer (score 24):

Maybe an other approach could be:

```
//Create the rectangle
cv::Rect roi(10, 20, 100, 50);
//Create the cv::Mat with the ROI you need, where "image" is the cv::Mat you want to extract the ROI from
cv::Mat image_roi = image(roi)
```

I hope this can help.

Comment: [Rect_](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d2/d44/classcv_1_1Rect__.html)(x, y, w, h), (x, y) left corner coordinate., and w, h are width and height of the rectangle.

Comment: Does this work for 16 bit data?